# How to set sed command correctly

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, zsh, quoting

When I try following commands, (I'd like to rewrite sql).

```
Day='2020/12/1'
Dir=/home/test/data


sql=`cat $Dir"/"$test".sql" | sed -e "s/Day/$Day/g"`
```

I suffered following errors.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'
```

Why the `s` is recognised as option ? why is this command couldnt work well ?

if someone has opinoin, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `/` as the separator for the `s/pattern/replacement/flags` `sed` command, then you need to escape the `/` in both pattern and replacement. Better to use a separator that doesn't occur in the pattern nor replacement:

```
Day='2020/12/1'
Dir=/home/test/data


sql=$(sed "s|Day|$Day|g" < "$Dir/$test.sql")
```

Since you're tagging `zsh`, you could also do:

```
sql=${"$(<$Dir/$test.sql)"//Day/$Day}
```

And then, you don't have to worry about this kind of issue nor about bytes not forming valid characters in the locale.

For multiple replacements:

```
typeset -A replace=(
  Day   "$Day"
  Month "$Month"
  Year  "$Year"
  '*'   Star
)
pattern="(${(j[|])${(kb@)replace}})"
set -o extendedglob
sql=${"$(<$Dir/$test.sql)"//(#m)$~pattern/$replace[$MATCH]}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can do it . I now search some method which can substitute multiple strings ... thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg, see edit to replace a list of strings with the zsh syntax.